# opening a react select dropdown inside a div is pushing another div in the same parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select and have generated few dropdowns. However, when I click on the top div, its pushing the bottom one below. I am using flex to display them inline. Could someone please help with my below issues. Really appreciate your help!

1. Opening/closing a div should not affect the other div. The expanded dropdown should overlay the botton div
2. Selecting an option from one drop down is selecting from the rest as well
3. Dropdowns are not getting clicked at times

   [image]

I am very new to CSS/React. Please help me. Below is the code:

```
const customStyles = {
    control:  (provided, state)=> ({
      ...provided,
      width: 210,
      position: 'relative',
      top: 40,
      // height: 25,
      // minHeight: 10,
      // overflow:'hidden'
    }),
    menu: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      width: 210,
      position: 'relative',
      top: 40
    }),
    menulist: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      width: 210,
    }),
    option: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      width: 210,
      height: 24,
      minHeight: 15,
      paddingTop:0,
      fontSize: '0.8em',

    }),
    placeholder: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      fontSize: '0.8em',
      color: colourOptions[1].color,
      fontWeight: 400,
      // position: 'relative',
      // top: 2,
      overflow:'hidden'
    }),
    multiValue: (styles, { data }) => {
      const color = colourOptions[0].color;
      return {
        ...styles,
        backgroundColor: colourOptions[0].color
      };
    },
    multiValueLabel: (styles, { data }) => ({
      ...styles,
      color: 'white',
      height: 18,
      minHeight: 15,
      fontSize:12,
      paddingTop:0
    }),
    multiValueRemove: (styles, { data }) => ({
      ...styles,
      color: colourOptions[1].color,
      ':hover': {
        backgroundColor: colourOptions[0].color,
        color: 'white',
      },
    }),
    dropdownIndicator : (styles, { data }) => ({
      ...styles,
      color: colourOptions[1].color,
      size:6,
      ':hover': {
        color: colourOptions[0].color,
      },
    }),
  };

class DefectsContainer extends Component {
     state = {
            teams:  [{ value: 'a', label: 'Alpha' },
            { value: 'b', label: 'Beta' },
            { value: 'c', label: 'Gamma' }],
            selectedOption:null
        };

        handleChange = selectedOption => {
            this.setState(
              { selectedOption },
              () => console.log(`Option selected:`, this.state.selectedOption)
            );
          };


      render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;

        return (
               <div className="defect-dashboard-main-div">    
                   <div className="defect-dashboard-container">     
                        <div className="filterContainer">
                            <div className="filterChildDiv">
                              <label className="filterHeader">Project</label>
                              <Select className="select-teams" closeMenuOnSelect={false} isMulti options={this.state.teams}
                                autosize={false} value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange} styles={customStyles}
                                placeholder="Select Project(s)..." theme={theme => ({
                                  ...theme,
                                  borderRadius: 3,
                                  borderColor: colourOptions[0].color,
                                  colors: {
                                      ...theme.colors,
                                      primary25: 'hotpink'
                                  }
                                  })}
                              />
                            </div>

                            <div className="filterChildDiv">
                              <label className="filterHeader">Category</label>
                              <Select className="select-teams" closeMenuOnSelect={false} isMulti options={this.state.teams}
                                autosize={false} value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange} styles={customStyles}
                                placeholder="Select Category..." theme={theme => ({
                                  ...theme,
                                  borderRadius: 3,
                                  borderColor: colourOptions[0].color,
                                  colors: {
                                      ...theme.colors,
                                      primary25: 'hotpink'
                                  }
                                  })}
                              />
                            </div>

....
```

My css file:

```
.filterContainer{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filterChildDiv{
    flex: 1;
    /* float: left; */
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.defect-dashboard-table-env-main{
    width:1400px!important;
    height: 1050px!important;
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:120px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the select menu is styled with absolute position, which allows it to overlay other elements by removing the element from the document flow. In your custom styles, you set menu position to relative, so the other relatively positioned elements move when the menu is opened and inserted into the document flow. Removing `position: relative` from the object returned by your customStyles.menu function will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu has css `position: absolute`, so it's bound to the parent container. As a result the dropdown menu changes the height of the parent container which is problematic in some cases, e.g. if the parent container is some kind modal dialog.

In those cases the dropdown menu should mimic the original behavior of selects where it overlaps other elements on the page. In order to achieve this behavior the dropdown menu must have `position:fixed` and the positioning (top, left, right) must be handled manually. It has to be attached to the position of the select control and the position must be manually change when scrolling the viewport.

```
const selectStyles = {
    valueContainer: () => ({
        padding: 10,
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center"
    }),
    menu: () => ({
        zIndex: 50,
        position: "fixed",
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
    }),
}
```

---

```
<Select
    styles={selectStyles}
    //...
/>
```